# How to try new permutations if previous solutions did not meet some conditions?

Tags: algorithm, prolog, clpfd

So, this is an exercise that I've been trying to solve for some time now. I get an input list like this `[a-b,b-c]`, which are nodes and arcs connecting nodes. The conditions are:

Nodes need to have an unique number associated, from 1 to N,

and arcs are required to have an unique number associated, from 1 to N-1, AND that number has to be the result of substracting the nodes that arc connects.

So the answer would be:

```
EnumNodos = [enum(3,a), enum(1,b), enum(2,c)],
EnumArcos = [enum(2,a‐b), enum(1,b‐c)]
```

So since I haven't been able to come up with an algorith for this, nor do I know if there is one, I thought, I could try every single possibility, since I know there IS a solution if the input is correct, and that way sooner or later I will get it.

I found an example of prolog permutation in which, if I give it some input list, it gives a permutation of it. Then (in console), if I hit ';' it gives me another one, and so on. I'm trying to include that code on my own.

I haven't finished yet but I would some help, specifically with the "looping" method in which I try to permute the options. I do not really know how you would say, in prolog, if this actions failed, try another, new permutation, different from each permutation tried before (WITHOUT giving ';' as input for the solution. Since there are many permutations that are going to fail, I want to check whether or not it fails, and if it does, try another one.

**EDIT** so I just found out setof... and I've been trying it out and I think I'm still missing one key part. As of right now I feel like I can get a list of every possibility I need with this: `setof(Out,perm(ListaEnum, SalidaPerm),X),`

But I still have trouble with the idea of FAILING then retrying. My idea so far is: I get the X result, and travel it as I would with any list. I check whether or not it does have unique numbers and so on, **and if it does not, I want to keep traveling that X. So I would be working on failure instead of success?? Should I even be doing this??**

```
% enumerate(CONNECTIONS_IN, NODES_OUT, ARCS_OUT)
%TODO query example of call: enumerate([a-b,b-c], EnumNodos, EnumArcos).

enumerate(C, EnumNodos, EnumArcos) :-
    enum_nodes(C, [], NodeListUnique, [], PermNodes, 1),
    loopPerm(C, NodeListUnique, EnumArcos, PermNodes, SalidaPerm).

% enum_nodes(CONNECTIONS_IN, NODES_IN, NODES_OUT, IDS_IN, IDS_OUT, START_ID) 
% Fills up NODES_OUT with unique nodes, and PERMOUT with IDS. New IDs start at START_ID...

enum_nodes([], N, N, M, M, _).
enum_nodes([A-B | T], N, NOUT, M, PERMOUT, ID) :-
    ensure_node(A, N, NTMP1, M, PERMNODESOUTA, ID, ID1),
    ensure_node(B, NTMP1, NTMP2, PERMNODESOUTA, PERMNODESOUTB, ID1, ID2),
    enum_nodes(T, NTMP2, NOUT, PERMNODESOUTB, PERMOUT, ID2).

% ensure_node(NODE, NODES_IN, NODES_OUT,IDS_IN, IDS_OUT, ID_IN, ID_OUT)
% Adds enum(ID_IN, NODE) to NODES_IN to produce NODES_OUT if NODE does not already exist in NODES_IN

ensure_node(NODE, NODES_IN, NODES_IN, PermNodesNOVALENin, PermNodesNOVALENin, ID, ID) :-
    member(NODE, NODES_IN), !.

ensure_node(NODE, NODES_IN, [NODE | NODES_IN], PERMIN, [ID_IN|PERMIN], ID_IN, ID_OUT) :-
    ID_OUT is ID_IN + 1.

%At this point I have a list of unique nodes and a list of IDs for said nodes, and I want to start calculatin permutations of this two lists until I find one that works.
loopPerm(C, NodeListUnique, EnumArcos, PermNodes, SalidaPerm):-
    crearEnum(NodeListUnique, PermNodes, ListaEnum),
    perm(ListaEnum, SalidaPerm),
    create_arcs(C, SalidaPerm, []),
    %%here is where code stops working properly
    loopPerm(C, EnumNodos, EnumArcos, PermNodes, SalidaPerm).

%crear_enum(NODES_IN, IDS_IN, enumLISTout)
%creates a list of enums to be permuted, TODO the idea here is that each call will change the list, so if it failed before, it should try a new one.
crearEnum([], [], []).
crearEnum([H1 | NodeListUnique], [H2| PermNodes], [enum(H2,H1)|Salida]):-
    crearEnum(NodeListUnique, PermNodes, Salida).


% create_arcs(CONNECTIONS_IN, NODES_IN, ARCS_OUT).  
% Create arcs - makes a list of arc(NODE_ID_1, NODE_ID_2)...

create_arcs([], _, _).
create_arcs([A-B | T], NODES, LISTARCS) :-
    ensure_arcs(A,B,NODES, LISTARCS, LISTARCS2),
    create_arcs(T, NODES, LISTARCS2).

%ensure_arcs(NODE_A, NODE_B, NODELIST, LISTARCSIN, LISTARCSOUT)
%builds a list of arcs TODO works WRONG when arc already was in the input. It should fail, but it just checks that is a member and moves on. So basically it works when arcs are new, because they are added properly, but not when arcs were already found (and as per the exercise it should fail and try another permutation).
ensure_arcs(A,B,NODES, LISTARCSIN, LISTARCSIN):-
    member(enum(NODE_ID_A, A), NODES),
    member(enum(NODE_ID_B, B), NODES),
    REMAINDER is abs(NODE_ID_A-NODE_ID_B),
    member(enum(REMAINDER,_), LISTARCSIN), !.

ensure_arcs(A,B,NODES, LISTARCSIN,[enum(REMAINDER, A-B) | LISTARCSIN]):-
    member(enum(NODE_ID_A, A), NODES),
    member(enum(NODE_ID_B, B), NODES),
    REMAINDER is abs(NODE_ID_A-NODE_ID_B).


perm([H|T], Perm) :-
   perm(T, SP),
   insert(H, SP, Perm).
perm([], []).

insert(X, T, [X|T]).
insert(X, [H|T], [H|NT]) :-
   insert(X, T, NT).
```

Here are some other examples I worked by hand in case they are needed. I also wanted to apologize because I'm not happy with the code in the slightest, it's just that I need to keep going instead of fixing what I'm sure are painful mistakes (but that I am not really able to fix, as of right now, it takes me way too long to get any code that works, even if barely).

```
    6a
  5    4
1b      2e
2       3
3c      5f
1
4d

 EnumNodos = [enum(6,a), enum(1,b), enum(2,e), enum(3,c), enum(5,f), enum(4,d)],

EnumArcos = [enum(5,a‐b), enum(4,a-e), enum(3,e-f), , enum(2,b-c), enum(1,c-d)]


    5a
  4   3
1b      2e
1       2
3c      4f

EnumNodos = [enum(5,a), enum(1,b), enum(2,e), enum(3,c), enum(4,f)],

EnumArcos = [enum(4,a‐b), enum(3,a-e), enum(1,b-c), , enum(2,e-f)]

    5a
  4    3
1b      2e
2
3c      
1
4d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that what you want to do is exactly what Prolog does **automatically**: It is called **backtracking** and means that Prolog will try *every possibility* until they are all exhausted.

So, in your case, you can formulate your whole task conceptually as:

```
solution(S) :-
    candidate(S),
    satisfies_all_constraints(S).
```

That's it. Prolog will generate all candidate solutions and report exactly those that "satisfy all constraints", which is what you need to describe in `satisfies_all_constraints/1`

For this reason, Prolog is called a **declarative language**: You describe **what** you want it to find. You do not particularly care **how** it finds these solutions.

Note that by using `setof/3` you circumvent this implicit backtracking and reify all solutions into a Prolog term that you can reason about *within* your program. This may be useful for example if you want to explore branches in a different order, or implement other search strategies altogether *within* Prolog. For the naive approach, no `setof/3` is needed, but rather a clear description of the solutions you want to find.

The longer answer is that such an approach (also called "generate and test") is definitely very appealing, useful and instructive in several cases, such as:

1. you have absolutely no idea **how** to find your results in any case
2. you want to generate **all solutions** in any case
3. generating all possibilities does not take a lot of time in any case
4. etc.

However, there are often **vastly faster** approaches for finding particular solutions, and your problem—although I have no idea what you actually want to find—seems to fall into this category.

Still, since this is also what you are asking for, I recommend you at least try the naive approach (*generate and test*), since it often results in very short and clear specifications of what you actually want, and with some luck, suffices to also get it, at least in small instances.

Comment: I know about backtracking but with any code that is longer than two lines I can't correctly see how is it going to do it, most of the time, and with this case in particular I can't see it at all. And honestly if I can't see what the code is going to do once it fails and goes back I do not know of a way to program. Maybe it can be done but I do not know it. And I'm probably complaining too much but I do not know how to do generate and test in this case, at all.

Comment: Try to think about it this way: Suppose I have already constructed a solution. Can you write down precisely, in Prolog, **which conditions** a solution satisfies so that you can say "Yes, that's really a solution"? Please focus on this declarative description of the properties any solution exhibits. You will find that this goes *a long way* towards you actual goal of *finding* such a solution. In fact, when programming in Prolog, it often suffices to state the properties a solution exhibits, and let Prolog do the rest.

Comment: Two things I would like to comment on this if you don't mind. I DO know the conditions, but as of right now in prolog I know how to say "if this DOES happen, keep travelling the list". And now I have the opposite case: "if this does NOT happen, keep travelling the list, because you haven't found the answer". Basically, I need to travel my list of permutations until I have found one that meets the requirement. I do not know to do that.

Comment: This is a very imperative way to think about the task, and it won't take you very far when programming in Prolog. This may sound cheap, but I assure you it is true: You can only go so far with imperative programming. Really think this through: For example, suppose I give you a *partially*  instantiated solution of the terms you are looking for. Does the imperative way of thinking about the task still cover this? Most likely not. Do not say "if this does happen"; say: "when does this hold?" Describe the conditions that characterize a solution. Take your time with this and think it through!

Comment: I know what you want me to see, but I do not have enough level to see it. As of right now I am not able to not think imperatively about this task (or most of them). I'll try though but I do not see what you say, sadly, because as I said when I try it I get stuck in problems of: how is this going to be traveling the list? how is this going to behave when the condition is not met? And so on, so I don't really get a picture of the whole "define when not how"

Comment: That's completely OK! It will definitely take you some time to think in terms of such relations, simply because it will lead to much more general programs than you are now used to. I will answer your followup questions in other threads.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what I wrote in the other answer, I now want to show you a **concrete** solution for your task. With at most very small modifications, it runs in SICStus Prolog, YAP, GNU and SWI:

```
graph_enumeration(Nodes, Arcs, NPs-APs, Vs) :-
        length(Nodes, N),
        pairs_keys_values(NPs, Nodes, VNs),
        pairs_keys_values(APs, Arcs, VAs),
        all_distinct(VNs),
        all_distinct(VAs),
        VNs ins 1..N,
        N1 #= N - 1,
        VAs ins 1..N1,
        append(VNs, VAs, Vs),
        maplist(arc_connects(NPs), APs).

arc_connects(NPs, arc(N1,N2)-V) :-
        member(N1-NV1, NPs),
        member(N2-NV2, NPs),
        V #= abs(NV1 - NV2).
```

Note the key ideas:

1. we describe what a solution looks like, i.e., what *holds* about a solution
2. we use CLP(FD) constraints to declaratively describe the requirements
3. we make the solution *very general* by staying within the pure monotonic subset of Prolog. No impure `!/0`, no if-then-else, *no nonsense*! Just describe *what holds*, and let Prolog do the rest to find actual solutions.

Example query and answer, for your initial test case:

```
?- graph_enumeration([a,b,c], [arc(a,b),arc(b,c)], E, Vs).
E = [a-_G6158, b-_G6164, c-_G6170]-[arc(a, b)-_G6176, arc(b, c)-_G6185],
Vs = [_G6158, _G6164, _G6170, _G6176, _G6185],
_G6158 in 1..3,
_G6232+_G6164#=_G6158,
all_distinct([_G6158, _G6164, _G6170]),
_G6164 in 1..3,
_G6273+_G6170#=_G6164,
_G6170 in 1..3,
_G6273 in -2.. -1\/1..2,
_G6185#=abs(_G6273),
_G6185 in 1..2,
all_distinct([_G6176, _G6185]),
_G6176 in 1..2,
_G6176#=abs(_G6232),
_G6232 in -2.. -1\/1..2 ;
false.
```

The **residual goals** mean that this is a **conditional** answer. There is a solution **iff** the residual constraints can be satisfied.

To find concrete solutions, we use the enumeration predicate `label/1`. For example:

```
?- graph_enumeration([a,b,c], [arc(a,b),arc(b,c)], E, Vs), label(Vs).
E = [a-1, b-3, c-2]-[arc(a, b)-2, arc(b, c)-1],
Vs = [1, 3, 2, 2, 1] ;
E = [a-2, b-1, c-3]-[arc(a, b)-1, arc(b, c)-2],
Vs = [2, 1, 3, 1, 2] ;
E = [a-2, b-3, c-1]-[arc(a, b)-1, arc(b, c)-2],
Vs = [2, 3, 1, 1, 2] ;
E = [a-3, b-1, c-2]-[arc(a, b)-2, arc(b, c)-1],
Vs = [3, 1, 2, 2, 1] ;
false.
```

This gives you *all solutions* that exist in this case. Note again that Prolog *automatically* generates all solutions for us on backtracking. Note also that we can use the predicate in all directions. For example, we can *verify* solutions, and complete partially instantiated solutions.